# In Functional Analysis proofs, why do scalars have to add up to 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

In functional analysis, sometimes there'll be questions involving linearly independent vectors where we want to make a linear combination of them and they'll start of by supposing that the scalars $\alpha_i$ satisfy $$\sum_1^n |\alpha_i| = 1\:\:\:(*)$$ This can be seen for example in the proof that for any normed space $X$ if we take $n$ linearly independent vectors $x_i$, then for any collection of $n$ scalars, we have $$||\sum_1^n \alpha_i x_i ||\geq C\sum_1^n |\alpha_i|$$ where $C$ is constant. But why do we need (*)?

Comment: Can you prove a more explicit example of the sorts of places this phenomena occurs? Also, do you mean $\left\|\sum_1^n \alpha_i x_i \right\|\geq C\sum_1^n |\alpha_i|$? In any case, the first thing that comes to mind is that assuming $\sum_1^n |\alpha_i| = 1$ is akin to assuming some norm $\|(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)\| = 1$, which is the assumption usually made when trying to prove, e.g., an operator is bounded.

Comment: In the example you cite, I think they use the fact that the unit sphere in any norm is compact. Also in that example, by scaling it suffices to prove the case when the norm is $1$, so you should assume so to simplify the problem.